# Unable to access /actuator endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I've got a small project running Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Streams with version `Greenwich.SR4`.

So far I've tried to include the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Wanting to have a `/check/health` endpoint which basically returns a code 200.

I've modified the config accordingly so that I don't have useless health configs within.

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/check
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.health.solr.enabled=false
management.health.elasticsearch.enabled=false
```

However, whenever I try to run `localhost:8080/check/health` a 404 is prompted. What could be happening?

Also mentioning that I've tried including my own `@RestController` but same behavior happens.

Comment: Which version did you use for `spring-boot-starter-parent`?

Answer (score 0):

The URL for the health check should be `http://localhost:8080/check/health`, not `/check/status`.

Comment: My bad, huge typo there. I meant `check/health`.

Comment: Works for me.  Can you try temporarily removing the Spring Cloud dependency, in order to see if that's causing an issue?  Are there any errors in the server logs?

Answer (score 0):

It is depends on the Spring-Boot version. After version 2.0 the path name is **manage**, so your right url is: `http://localhost:8080/check/health`

You can also change that with (.yml version):

```
management:
  context-path: /manage
  security:
    enabled: false
```